# A function of my class causes my program to crash

Tags: c++, class, vector, dynamic-arrays

I'm doing a simple_vector class, which can only contain doubles, using dynamic arrays. Somehow, my function push is making my program crash, and I don't know what's going on. When I call it, the console stays still for a moment and then immediately ends the main.

I have no idea...

```
void simple_vector::push(double value){
if (length == capacity){
    expandCapacity();
}
  array[length++] = value;
}
```

expandCapacity() duplicates the capacity of the array and copies its content.

It shouldn't enter the if, considering that I'm doing the push to an empty vector.

Comment: My advice is to use a debugger like the one in Visual Studio. With a debugger you can step through this code a line at a time and see how it behaves and also inspect your variables before and after each line is executed.

Comment: You really did not give us much to go on. We can only guess what you have done wrongly. The problem may not even be in the code that is presented.

Answer (score 0):

where is the line your program crashed.

**first**, assume that expandCapacity() crashing your program. i have no idea,, because there is no information about expandCapacity() fucntion. so you should ask your questrion cleary.

**second**, assume that array[length++] crahsing your program. then length value is bigger than your array size. **In additional**, array start from 0 index. so you declare 10 size array, then you can access array[0] ~ array[9].

thanks.

Comment: and where is declaration of length, capacity and array?